# Username and passwords - sane constraints?

Tags: authentication, passwords

If you'd write an application where some privileged user has the option to create new users, what would be sane constraints concerning `username` and `password`? E.g. "username must be at least 8 characters' or 'password must contain at least a number...'. Are there any good reads about this topic?

Comment: IMO, password constraints simply make users pick passwords they can't remember which they then write down or email to themselves, thus creating more insecurity. Simply advise them of the complexity of the password as they are typing and allow them to pick their own regardless.

Comment: http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/magazine/7090407.stm

Comment: Further comment - I often have very complex passwords (as rated by trusted security tools) that do not pass some institution's bespoke "secure password requirements" implementation. It's stupid to require the addition of some type of character when a cracker can read the requirements as well and tailor their attacks to it.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1091&bih=781&q=what+makes+a+good+password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passwords should be at least 8 characters and contain alpha, numeric, >1 special character & combo upper and lower case.

EDIT:  WHY 8 CHARCTERS or more?  Check these [stats on password hacking](http://www.lockdown.co.uk/?pg=combi&s=articles).  By making it 8 characters or greater, the time cost of a brute force attack is greatly increased.  Then add in encryption with salt and you have a better chance of being protected.

LOTS of details on [password protection & user security](http://www.openwall.com/articles/PHP-Users-Passwords).

Comment: And why is that? A slightly more rigorously explained answer might be called for on this topic.

Comment: it's not my downvote, but I would guess it was due to the lack of evidence in your original assertions. To be honest, your expansions with links doesn't really provide anything compelling either. A discussion of the exponential rise in difficulty for brute-forcing longer keys and larger key spaces seems to be the minimum for a useful answer.

Comment: +1 The second article is amazing!